# Notify me when this product is in stock for Configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, simple-product, out-of-stock, stock-alert, notify-me

I want to set link "Notify me when this product is in stock" for the out of stock child product.

For simple product, When the product is out of stock, we can see this link "Notify me when this product is in stock" on PDP. Please check screenshot below,

[image]

So, Want to implement same functionality for the child product of config product. See the screenshot below,
[image]

Here, XS and Orange color product is "out of stock". We only get know when adding product to cart. So, Can we implement this same as simple product? Like "Notify Me" link should be visible instead of "Add to Cart" before product adding to cart.

Please let me know if you guys have any solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
You Can Overide swatch-renderer.js in own module.In js create own function and impliment notify functionality.

In this js i have create own function and i was get click attribute product id and ajax through i have send product id my controller and get child product available or not accordding respone i was create notify functionality.

Comment: Do you have the code for reference? If yes, Can you provide or paste here?

Comment: Please let me know if you have any code reference or flow.